# How can I un-burn a bridge?

Tags: employer-relations, human-resources

I worked in a company more than 2 years ago which I still want to work, after this time. But when I left I did not leave under the best terms. Now when I tried to come back the HR told me that I from technical point of view I'm ok, these past difficulties mean I did not get rehired.

- How can I change the bad impression I made in the past when I have changed? What can I do to convince the company to give me a second chance?

Comment: Hi florin, welcome to the Workplace SE. Can you [edit] your post to clarify. What exactly are you trying to make go away?  Also, "I kind another case for this question".  It's not clear what you mean here too. You can continue editing your post now that it's posted, and editing it will help users understand your problem. Good luck! :)

Comment: OK, edited it. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: It sounds like you quit your job, then tried to re-apply, but they denied you? Is that correct?  Also, how do you think you made a bad impression? Hope this helps you clarify.

Comment: Yeah I did so, quit and now I am trying to go back.

Comment: Is going back an option?

Comment: We modified your question to clear up what you are asking.  I think this is a good general question.

Comment: One counter question, why do you want to go back to work with your previous company?

Comment: because it was better there and lots more fun there

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Consider it a burned bridge and let it go.

Your first impression will last a lot longer than you think, and you may not have changed as much as you think since you left.  Let it go.

---

note: the above was written as an answer to [the original question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/11520/3).  The edited question is much more mellow.

Comment: -1: It may turn out to be true that the OP won't be able to go back to their old job, but this doesn't really answer the question or provide any back up to what was stated.

Comment: @GreenMatt in that case I have to be explicit: I do not think he can do what he asks for. Sole exception might be if he has a large portfolio of open source projects showing he now is extremely proficient AND a good team player.  Otherwise I think it is a lost cause.

Comment: I understood from the original answer that you don't think he can recover.  (You may be correct.)  However, you don't provide any reason for that, such as personal experience trying to do this yourself, studies of people who've tried to do this, etc.

Comment: @GreenMatt no I don't.  And that is my personal opinion, based on how _I_ would feel about rehiring a person who had behaved as described in the original question. Pure emotion.  First impressions last. If you disagree, feel free to write a better answer

Comment: We're in agreement that overcoming impressions and emotions can be tough.  If I believed I had a better answer, I would write it.  Unfortunately, this answer fails to meet the criteria set forth in the [FAQ](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#how-should-i-answer); as is, it is really more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Upon reading the revision of the question that this was in response to, I have to agree. Everything about that screams that florin89 still thinks "I made a bad impression because I was too smart for those idiots and they thought my good ideas were bad ones." Let it go.

Answer (score 8):

I think Thorbjorn Ravn Andersen is probably correct. But if there's hope at all for you to reconcile with the company, it would likely have to be through the people that you worked with before and it would have to take place outside the company; you're unlikely to reconcile during an interview or application process.

Remember that although companies can be soulless and cold, they are run by people. It's people that you must have left a bad impression with the first time and it's probably those people that told HR they would prefer not to rehire. In fact, it wouldn't surprise me if there is actually a "rehire" flag on employee records at some companies.

Do you have any contact with your former co-workers or supervisors? If you do, and you're on at least neutral terms, have a lunch with them and discuss your interest. If you were a jerk in the past, it's a chance to make amends. If they were the ones who were jerks, well, then I'm not sure why you'd want to go back, but at least you could discuss things with them.

I actually did return to a company that I'd left and that's how I did it. I met with my old supervisor outside work and expressed my interest in returning.

Comment: In addition to having lunch, you could get involved in groups which former your co-workers are part of, for example: a charity, a user group, sports teams, school groups, or social groups.  By being seen outside work, you will (hopefully) show your good side.  (Even if that doesn't work with your former co-worker, you may make new connections.)  Be sure to pick a group you have some genuine interest in, as you want to avoid the appearance of "faking it".

Comment: Actually I did receive word of the need of me coming back from some colleagues of mine. Actually my old chief and his friend.

Comment: @florin89 this is very important information. In that case contact those again and ask them to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I happened to face similar situation. I was working with an organization which I liked a lot. Then due to some personal reasons, I had to leave it and I did not leave with a very good impression.

Then after 1.5 year I tried to join back. I cleared the interview but the HR got not so good feedback about me from my previous supervisor and I could not join.
However, the organization had a rule that the previous supervisor's feedback will be taken/considered only if the employee is joining back with 2 years. So I tried again after 3 years. This time I cleared the interview and luckily it did not go to that supervisor for feedback.

They looked at the old record of the type of work I had done earlier which was good in my case. I am now working there again.

So my point is, if you had done good work there earlier, but made a bad impression only when you were leaving, you can ask them to consider your earlier work. Also you can show the type of work you have been doing after leaving which can show that you have improved since you left.

Hope this would be of some help.